# Is it possible to put a self-defined piecewise function in my objective function using scip python interface?

Tags: scip

in my optimization problem, I want to put a piecewise function in my objective function. i.e f(x)=0.3 for x in (0,0.1）;f(x)=0.5 for x in (0.1,0.4), etc and I'm solving for a series of x i.e. x1, x2,...xn subject to a bunch of constraints. Can I put the f(x) I defined in my objective function?I'm using the python interface of scip

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, this is not (yet) supported. You would need to model your problem differently.

SOS1 and SOS2 constraints can be generated using the Python interface and may be of good use as pointed out in the link in stefan's comment.

Comment: Do u have any suggestions on how to model this kind of optimization problem?

Comment: Is it possible to put it in the constraint?

Comment: Google points me to http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.de/2015/10/piecewise-linear-functions-in-mip-models.html

Comment: On a separate note, is it possible to input a self defined piecewise function into the method addCons of the scip python interface?

Comment: No, the ```addCons()``` method only accepts linear or quadratic equations or inequalities.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. So making use of the SOS1 constraints, it should be doable? I am also a little confused about how the addConsSOS1 is implemented. Are there any examples?

Comment: Well, you simply call ```model.addConsSOS1(vars)``` with ```vars``` being the list of variables that are supposed to be in the special ordered set, i.e. of which only one can be non-zero.